# How can I render a partial using a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

In my application, the user clicks on one of three choices.  When the user clicks on the choice, I want to grab that choice and then use a popup to display more information about it.  However, I want to use a controller to make an api call based on the user choice so that I can get more data about the choice they chose.

How can I create a function in my controller to do just this?

Comment: @rkon I can create the popup.  I just don't know how to manipulate the data in a controller function.  I am at a loss as to where to indicate that the partial is being controlled by a certain controller function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a partial I suppose you want to call the controller through AJAX. I would solve this by adding `remote: true` to the links representing the three choices, and setting up the actions in the controller accordingly.

For instance:

`<%= link_to 'choice 1', choice_path, class:'choice-link', data: { choice: 1 }, remote: true %>`.

```
# controller
def choice_action
  # some filter based on which choice (1, 2 or 3) the user chose
  render partial: 'path/to/partial', layout: false if request.xhr?
end
```

The `layout` flag indicates that you just return the HTML generated by the partial, and do not wrap it in the application layout you normally would when rendering server-generated HTML templates.

In order to append the HTML to your DOM I'd use a listener on the choice links, for instance like so:

```
$('.choice-link').on 'ajax:success', (data, status, xhr) ->
  $('#popup').html(data)
```

Comment: Ok.  I tried this, and I am getting a response, but the ajaxsuccess is not working.

Comment: @DavidMckee: Please note the colon -> `ajax:success`. It's also important that you bind the handler on the element which triggers the ajax call (or its parent).